# How to force child component re-render in Vue 3/Nuxt3?

Tags: vuejs3, pinia, nuxt3

I am trying to use key based component re-rendering. Binding a ref value to the key attribute of a child component is causing an infinite console error logs.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`

The error is coming from Vue, not my component.

[image]

I have a pinia value that is set as a ref using:

```
const {
    ...
    shippingCountry,
    ...
} = storeToRefs(cartStore)
```

And the ref is bound to the child like so:

```
<FormZipCodeField id="shippingZipcode"
                   ...
                   :key="shippingCountry"
                   @changed="({value}) => cartStore.setShippingZipcode(value)"/>
```

The component gets re-rendered as expected, the setup function is being hit and is calling a console log. But then I get the infinite loop of console logs.

Even if I use a basic ref value that is not hooked up to a pinia ref, I get the same result. So it must not be a problem with Pinia:

```
const test = ref('test')

const handleCountryChanged = ({value}) => {
    ...
    test.value = "bust"
}
```

And the ref is bound to the child like so:

```
<FormZipCodeField id="shippingZipcode"
                   ...
                   :key="test"
                   @changed="({value}) => cartStore.setShippingZipcode(value)"/>
```

Has anyone ever done something like this an maybe has a fix or an alternative solution?

Comment: There is no access to an `id` property n the provided code. Can you provide the code where the error occurs?

Comment: The child component does not try to access any `.id` properties, the error is coming from Vue

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the error was coming from a chrome extension of mine.